# Cannot Import GTK in Ubuntu Python 2.7

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk, pygtk, python-idle

I'm trying to import GTK in Ubuntu Python 2.7, and I get the following error. PyGTK imports just fine. When I `import gtk`, I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1413, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/MultiCall.py", line 167, in handler
    r = l[i](event)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1140, in enter_callback
    self.runit()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1181, in runit
    more = self.interp.runsource(line)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 619, in runsource
    return InteractiveInterpreter.runsource(self, source, filename)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/code.py", line 87, in runsource
    self.runcode(code)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 759, in runcode
    self.tkconsole.endexecuting()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 940, in endexecuting
    self.showprompt()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1205, in showprompt
    self.resetoutput()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1217, in resetoutput
    if self.history:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 64, in idle_showwarning
    lineno, file=file, line=line))
TypeError: idle_formatwarning() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Open a terminal (Applications > Accessories Terminal) and at the command prompt type `python`. After the `>>>` type `import gtk` and see if it imports without any errors now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue12438) in idle.  Looking at the last line of that error message:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 64, in idle_showwarning
    lineno, file=file, line=line))
TypeError: idle_formatwarning() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'
```

This is saying that the warning.idle_showwarning method does not have an argument "file".

Sure enough looking at /usr/lib/python2.7/warnings.py

```
def formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line=None)
```

There is no such argument.

This apparently has been resolved in source control but I do not think it has made it into a release yet.  I would just hack the /usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py file and remove the offending argument from line 64.

Then try it again...

Comment: That solved it! For anyone who doesn't know how to edit that file, go to Terminal and type "sudo nano /usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py".

Answer (score 1):

Try it outside of IDLE. The error here is in IDLE, not your code.

Create a new script that contains `import gtk` and save it anywhere.

From the command line, in the directory where your script is located, run `python whatever_your_scripts_name_is.py`.

See if you get an error. You may not be able to `import gtk` in IDLE.

Edit: There is apparently a [problem with GTK and IDLE](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1489314.html) in some situations on Ubuntu.

Try a different Python shell; I'd recommend [IPython](http://ipython.org/) which you can install with Synaptic or `sudo apt-get install ipython`.

Comment: I'm able to import gtk on my Windows 7 installation of Python, so that isn't it. Also, where is the gtk.py located? A search has turned up nothing.

Comment: I don't _know_ where it's located. IDLE is still masking the real error (or else the error is with the Ubuntu version of IDLE), so you should still do this, it will clear up what the error is with -- it doesn't matter where gtk.py is located.

Comment: It says "No such file or directory." However, it says that for the functional pygtk.py as well.

Comment: Did you try to do `python gtk.py`? That's NOT what I asked you to do. Create a NEW `.py` file, and put `import gtk` in it, then run the newly created script. And please, don't report errors as "it said". Post the actual console text in your post, so I know what "it" was and the full error.

Comment: Ah, misread your original post. I created a script as directed, with just the line "import gtk", and I saved it and ran it in Terminal. No error. However, it still throws the same problem in IDLE.

Comment: Yeah, it's a problem with IDLE. See my edit; easiest solution is to use IPython.